# Magento 2 GraphQL - How to build a Tree structure in response

Tags: magento2, category-tree, graphql, response

I have created a custom module for megamenu. I have created the graphQL query for that also. The query returns the correct result for level 0.  How can I get the tree structure?
Here is my graphql schema.

```
    type Query {
    menus(
       menuType: String @doc(description: "Defines the filter to use for searching menus")
    ): Menus @resolver(class: "Test\\MegamenuGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\Megamenu") @doc(description: "Retrieves the menus based on filter if filter applied.")
}

type Menus @doc(description: "The collection of menus .") {
    items: [Menu] @doc(description: "An array of menuss")
    
}

type Menu @doc(description: "Contains details about each of the menu.") {
    Type: String @doc(description: "The Menu Type")
    menu_items: [MenuItems] @doc(description: "The details of menu")
}

type MenuItems @doc(description: "Contains details about each of the menu.") {
    menu_id: ID @doc(description: "The menu Id")
    title: String @doc(description: "The menu title")
    menu_type:String @doc(description: "The menu type")
    link: String @doc(description: "The menu link")
    image: String @doc(description: "The menu image")
    position:ID @doc(description: "The menu position")
    parent_id: ID @doc(description: "The parent menu id")
    parent_name: String @doc(description: "The parent menu name")
    children: [MenuItems] @doc(description: "The details of menu")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento have default API for tree menu.

```
{
  categories(
    filters: { parent_id: { in: ["2"] } }
    pageSize: 10
    currentPage: 1
  ) {
    total_count
    items {
      uid
      level
      name
      path
      url_key
      children_count
      children {
        uid
        level
        name
        path
        children_count
        children {
          uid
          level
          name
          path
        }
      }
    }
    page_info {
      current_page
      page_size
      total_pages
    }
  }
}
```